# Automate entering text into a field where editable field is defined in angular and my test framework is selenium webdriverio

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, cucumber, webdriver-io

I am trying to enter text into a field in a form. The action on the field is defined in angular and I am not able to locate editable object. . Here is my code piece:

```
**Scenario**:
When I enter "xyz" into the "Headline" field
// Entering strings
When('I enter( the) {string} into the {string} field', enterText);
```

```
**selection**
/**
 * Enters specific text into an element
 * @param {string} text The text to enter
 * @param {string} field The field key for an element
 * @returns {Promise<WebElement|Error>} The obtained element as a promise
 */
export async function enterText(text, field) {
  console.log('enter text 1');
  const element = getSelector(field);
  console.log(element);
  await World.browser.setValue(element, text);
```

Code where text is to be entered is written in angular and text is being entered in

tag not in  tag

I have tried using css as selector 
`div > storyline-editor > cue-storyline > div > cue-story-element-editor-container > mouse-handler > ng-transclude > div > cue-story-element-editor > cue-text-story-element-editor > mouse-handler > ng-transclude > cue-rte > div > div > p`

If I use above selector in selenium IDE and run the code it works fine but it is not working for my framework

1) Checking New Article Page Elements14 I enter "Test Headline" into the "Headline" field:
`[chrome #0-0] unknown error: cannot focus element`

Comment: Welcome to SO !! Please read [MCVE] , provide full context of web element as in html structure ,

Answer (score 0):

You will see Failed: unknown error: cannot focus element error when you are trying to set values to an element which is not an input.

You need to set the focus or perform a click on the element before setting the value to it.

```
export async function enterText(text, field) {
console.log('enter text 1');
const element = getSelector(field);
console.log(element);
await element.click()
await World.browser.setValue(element, text);
```

If that does not work use execute javascript method.